# SimpleXMLElement document - how to return value of children attributes in SimpleXMLElement Object?

Tags: php, object, simplexml

Here is the XML:

```
<Routes>
    <Route type="source">
        <Table>
            <Tablename>incoming</Tablename>
            <Fields>
                <Fieldsname ref="description" name="Route Name">description</Fieldsname>
                <Fieldsname name="CID Match">cidnum</Fieldsname>
                <Fieldsname name="DID Match">extension</Fieldsname>
                <Fieldsname ref="dest">destination</Fieldsname>
            </Fields>
        </Table>

    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Then my instantiation of it in PHP:

```
$doc    = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);
```

`print_r($doc->Route[0])` shows this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => source
        )

    [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [Table] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Tablename] => incoming
            [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Fields] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Fieldsname] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => description
                            [1] => cidnum
                            [2] => extension
                            [3] => destination
                        )

                    [comment] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Notice how the root value has the `@attributes` array. Why doesn't `$doc->Routes[0]->Table->Fields->Fieldsname` have `@attributes`? I realize I can get it via `attributes()`, but is there a way to make it be included in `$doc`?

**EDIT**
Apparently `print_r()` doesn't display *every* value in the array/object, exploring all children etc. Or perhaps `SimpleXMLElement` doesn't return it unless requested (seems like it should all be stored in `$doc`). If you do `print_r($doc->Route[0]->Table->Fields->Fieldsname[0]);`, it returns

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [ref] => description
            [name] => Route Name
        )

    [0] => description
)
```

Which shows the data I am looking for. But if I do a `print_r($doc->Route[0]->Table->Field);` the data does not appear.

Comment: `print_r()` is intended for debugging. If you are certain you can get the attrs by calling `attributes()` on those nodes, why worry about `print_r()`?

Comment: It's more that I want `$doc` to contain all the correct values, including `attributes` for children, rather than worrying about `print_r()`. I just used `print_r` to show the `$doc` object/array.

Comment: Can you load it via `simplexml_load_file()`?

Comment: just tried it, it returns the same values as `SimpleXMLElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleXMLElement` object does some very advanced things in PHP. It implements a lot of the "magic" hooks that PHP provides so that it works in things like `foreach()` and is meant to be treated like a "black box". So because of that, using `print_r()` on it will give you misleading and incomplete information. You just can't rely on `print_r()` (or `var_dump()`) on a `SimpleXMLElement` object.

The way to debug the structure in a `SimpleXMLElement` is to simply look for the elements you're after: things like `isset($xmlnode->child)` work, for instance. So `is_array($doc->Route[0]->Table->Fields->Fieldsname)` will be true.